# Multivariate Optimization keeps returning same initial values

Tags: r, optimization

I have the code

```
INJ.1<-"I01 I02 I03 I04 I05         
2.78E+02    1.82E+03    3.62E+02    2.90E+02    7.73E+02
7.92E+02    1.21E+03    9.33E+02    6.32E+02    5.10E+02
2.30E+03    7.54E+02    9.60E+02    6.29E+02    1.05E+03
3.61E+03    3.05E+02    7.77E+02    5.87E+02    1.02E+03
3.89E+02    1.35E+03    7.66E+02    4.00E+02    7.43E+02
1.31E+03    1.63E+03    8.95E+02    3.85E+02    1.10E+02
1.39E+03    1.16E+03    9.07E+02    4.99E+02    2.48E+02
1.94E+03    1.09E+03    8.34E+02    5.22E+02    2.48E+02
2.04E+03    1.11E+03    7.85E+02    2.67E+02    4.27E+02
1.06E+03    1.36E+03    8.80E+02    6.13E+02    7.16E+02
1.40E+03    1.29E+03    8.65E+02    6.17E+02    9.79E+02
1.20E+03    1.68E+03    6.78E+02    6.10E+02    9.30E+02
1.45E+03    1.49E+03    7.66E+02    3.81E+02    1.07E+03
1.16E+03    1.58E+03    1.09E+03    5.33E+02    8.38E+02
1.33E+03    1.38E+03    9.10E+02    6.29E+02    8.80E+02

"
INJ<-as.matrix(read.table(text=INJ.1, header=T))
PRD.1<-"P01                
981.32019             
1062.5702             
1439.7673             
1694.0723             
1085.1016             
1243.6089             
1191.5941             
1302.2167             
1333.5266             
1242.0212             
1342.6954             
1371.2767             
1394.1171             
1400.7926             
1373.1791             
"
PRD<-as.matrix(read.table(text=PRD.1, header=T))
tao=as.matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1))
lambda=as.matrix(c(0.0251879,0.1599486,0.1812318,0.2626731,0.3355733,0.3221295,-1.3343501))
i.dash=matrix(ncol=ncol(INJ), nrow=(nrow(INJ)))
fn1 <- function (tao){
  for (i in 1:ncol(INJ))
    for (j in 1:nrow (INJ))
      temp=0
  for (k in 1:j)
    i.dash[j,i]=(1/tao[i])*exp((k-j)/tao[i])*INJ[k,i]+i.dash[j,i]



  target = abs(700-sum(colSums(i.dash)))
}
ini=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

ans1<-optim(par=ini,fn1,hessian=TRUE)
```

I need to optimize the values of `tao` as shown in the function. The code keeps giving the same initial values in in addition to that I noticed that the matrix calculation inside the function `fn1` wasn't done. I have more than one question in addition to the main question which is how can I solve this case to achieve the min of o `target`:

1. Can we issue non calculation commands inside the function for example: assigning and creating matrices, vectors operations and manipulations..etc?
2. Are these changes going to be available after we exit the function?
3. In my case I am using the parameters `values` in some calculation firstly to prepare the objective function and then I do the optimization on them is that an acceptable approach in R?
4. I would like some one to give me as much as a starting point to start optimizing this function.

Comment: I am not sure what the function is supposed to do.  Perhaps link to another site that uses the function.  Also, I do not understand what tao is.  Tao appears to be a constant, always equal to one.  You seem to define it equal to one, in which case it might simply drop out of the equation.  Maybe I am wrong.  Also, what is i.dash?  In your code it appears to be a matrix of 75 missing observations that are never defined since summing anything and a missing observation gives a missing observation.  Also, if there are 5 values of tao and you want to estimate tao, why are there 12 initial values?

Comment: Also, if you know the correct answer for the problem, please post it so others can use it to determine whether their code it correct.

Comment: One more question, is your function creating the likelihood and you want to estimate parameters by maximizing that likelihood?

Comment: @MarkMiller (1) the function minimizes the value of `target` (2) `tao` is the variable of interest that I want to optimize but I need to use its initials in the obj. function construction. (3) `i.dash` is a matrix defined before the function and I am filling it inside the function which is part of my question as I get NA fills. (4) I've edited `tao` values number to be five. (5) I don't have the correct answer yet (6) my function is supposed to minimize the value `target`...thanks

Comment: Since tao is defined as the constant 1 outside the function I am not sure how it can be estimated as anything else.  I can try to look more closely tomorrow.  Also, maybe try setting i.dash = 0 in the first row and first column outside the function.  Maybe use na.rm = TRUE in colSums.  It would really help me if you linked to a website or paper or textbook where this function has been used and the correct answer known.

Comment: @MarkMiller..Thanks..the issue is that I have to have a value for `tao` in order to construct the function. the function is part of an optimization model we use in the oil field and it's derived from the continuity equation. I have attached an image for you explaining the equation https://www.dropbox.com/s/ta487y6yzi6j0av/Untitled%20%282%29.png

Comment: Okay, but you have to define tao as a parameter in the function.  I will look into that tomorrow.  I still need to find the equation in a textbook or website where someone else presents a worked example.  Your link is to an equation you wrote.  That helps, but I would like to see the equation in an  independent source with a worked example and known solution.  What is the name of the equation?  I could use that to try to find it myself.  If I find the equation in an independent source I can verify any code I might write.  I did not find this equation in Wikipedia under 'continuity equation'.

Comment: You're asking for trouble (disaster) by referring to `INJ` inside your function without passing `INJ` into the function.  If you change `INJ` in the parent environment, `fn1` will use the new values without making that obvious to you.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The value of `INJ` won't be changed through out the code that's why I didn't pass to the function

Comment: @MarkMiller below is a PhD dissertation link for what I am working on, refer to  section 6.3.1 and the the equation that I've uploaded previously is in there I am looking at the second term only, the objective function for simplicity I made it 700-this equation https://www.dropbox.com/s/o1cbqjcn6h02t0g/alyousefa23661.pdf